# Countdown slowing down eventhough there is Time.deltatime (Unity) (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am quite a beginner at coding and I am trying to make a countdown that counts Days/Hours/Minutes/Seconds. I have this code right here and everything works alright, but when I try to put bigger numbers like 168800 (to count for 2 days), it slows down to the point that it stops and won’t count anymore. Do you know how could I fix this?

Thank you.

```
`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Component")]
    public TextMeshProUGUI timerText;

    [Header("Timer Settings")]
    public float currentTime; 
    public bool countDown;

    [Header("Limit Settings")]
    public bool hasLimit;
    public float timerLimit;

    private bool SetTimerText = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        currentTime = countDown ? currentTime -= Time.DeltaTime : currentTime += Time.DeltaTime;

        int seconds = (int)(currentTime % 60);
        int minutes = (int)(currentTime / 60) % 60;
        int hours = (int)(currentTime / 3600) % 24;
        int days = (int)(currentTime / 86400);

        string currentTimeS = string.Format("{0:0} days {1:0} hours {2:00} minutes {3:00} seconds", days,hours,minutes,seconds);

        if((hasLimit) && ((countDown && currentTime <= timerLimit) || (!countDown && currentTime >= timerLimit)))
        {
            currentTime = timerLimit;
            SetTimerText = true;
            timerText.color = Color.red;
            enabled = false;
        }

        SetTimerText = true;

        if(SetTimerText){timerText.text = currentTimeS; SetTimerText = false;}
    }

}`
```

Comment: [Worth reading this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). The gaps between floats become bigger as they get larger, at some point for a large enough `f`, `f == f - dt`

Comment: Try using a `TimeSpan` struct for example `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Time.DeltaTime)`

Answer (score -1):

You are most likely encountering the floating point error. You can use `int` and tick every second in a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to be extra sure that your timer ticks perfectly and with good performance.

```csharp
public int currentTime;

void Start(){
  StartCoroutine(Timer());
}

IEnumerator Timer()
{
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
  if (countDown)
  {
    --currentTime;
  }
  else
  {
    ++currentTime;
  }
  /*rest of the code can also go here*/
}
```

The only real disadvantage of this code is that micro pauses caused by you flicking `countDown` aren't taken into account.

Comment: Hi, I see the point, however, when I try to do this it won't let me because Time.DeltaTime is a float whereas currentTime is an int.

Comment: @TensiK sorry, idiot me skipped over the change that actually makes it work. Code fixed, it should actually work now.